# Filter all repeated observation with at least one of the record per group with non-missing cusip identifier

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset containing company information. Specifically, there are two columns called CUSIP and RCID. I want to first take out all observations with repeated RCID. So if my dataset is as follows, I want to take out records 3,4,5,6,7,8. I'm able to do this with

```
fin_rcid_dup = df['rcid'].duplicated(keep=False)
filtered_df = df[fin_rcid_dup]
```

| Index | RCID | CUSIP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 478923 | . |
| 2 | 346422 | . |
| 3 | 362736 | . |
| 4 | 362736 | 4637468 |
| 5 | 362736 | . |
| 6 | 673253 | . |
| 7 | 673253 | . |
| 8 | 362736 | . |

And I want to further take out the group of records (observations with same rcid belongs to the same group) with at least one of them having non-missing cusip, that is I want to take out 3,4,5,8, but not 6,7 because all records of rcid == 673253 miss cusip. Do you know how can I do this?

Thank you!

I tried

```
has_duplicates = df['rcid'].duplicated(keep=False)

cusip_not_missing = df['cusip'].isna()

filtered_df = df[has_duplicates & cusip_not_missing]
```

But in this way I can only take out 4 because for other records of rcid == 362736 , they have missing cusip

Comment: `cusip_not_missing = df['cusip'].isna()` should be `cusip_not_missing = df['cusip'].notna()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `notna` and [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
has_duplicates = df['rcid'].duplicated(keep=False)

cusip_not_missing = df['cusip'].notna().groupby(df['rcid']).transform('any')

filtered_df = df[has_duplicates & cusip_not_missing]
```